# Decoding a base64 url in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, base64

I currently have landing pages taking the following shape :

`http://rootdomain/index.html?ref=[base64encoded-ref]&text=[base64encoded-text]`

When I watch my stats in google analytics, I have urls looking like

`http://rootdomain/index.html?ref=c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw==&text=bWFyd2Fubg==`

but I'd like to see

`http://rootdomain/?index.html?ref=stackoverflow&text=marwann` for example.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't do this in GA. It doesn't support it. You'll have to read the data out of GA and parse it yourself. Also what does this have to do with Javascript?

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks. I thought there may have been a way to "modify" the url parsed by GA with javascript when the analytics tag fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oki so you can do this, but it can be tricky, so be careful.

***Without GTM:***

So on the page with Universal analytics, you can actually tell what must be the value that will be recorded. you can decode your path using JS and pass it like below:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': '/YOUR-CUSTOM-PATH' });
```

---

***Using GTM:***

Changing the "`dp`" value can be accomplished in GTM by setting the desired value in the page field, under "Fields to set":
[image]

Let me know if you have doubts.